# Можно ли добавить в primary key колонку из другой таблицы

Tags: sql, база-данных, oracle

Прошу помочь решить такую проблему:
Имеются две таблицы c primary key

```
create table user_table
 (user_id number(4,0), 
  user_name varchar2(10 BYTE),
  office_id number(4,0),
  constraint user_pk primary key (user_id, office_id)
 );


 create table office_table
 (user_id number(4,0), 
  user_name varchar2(10 BYTE),
  office_id number(4,0),
  department_id number(4,0), 
  constraint office_pk primary key (user_id, office_id, department_id)
 );
```

Можно как-то primary key в user_table расширить до подобного вида:

```
constraint user_pk primary key (user_id, office_id, office_table.department_id)
```

То есть, появилась необходимость в user_table внести дополнительную уникальность записей по department_id, но в user_table не особо хочется для этого создавать новую колонку и дублировать информацию в двух таблицах, т.к. работать буду только с office_table.department_id.

Пытался сам найти решение, но видимо неправильно гуглил. Буду признателен, если подскажете, как в таких ситуациях поступать.

Answer (score 0):

Объедините user_table и office_table в одну таблицу. 2 таблицы с одинаковой структурой и данными "не лучшая" практика. т.е.

```
 create table total_table
 (user_id number(4,0), 
 user_name varchar2(10 BYTE),
 office_id number(4,0),
 department_id number(4,0), 
 constraint total_pk primary key (user_id, office_id, department_id)
 );
```

Если требуется различать данные в user_table и office_table. Можно завести таблицу type_table:

```
create table type_total_table
 (type_id number(4,0), 
 type_name varchar2(10 BYTE)
 );
```

И затем добавить атрибут в total_table:

```
create table total_table
(...
type_id number(4,0),
constraint total_pk primary key (user_id, office_id, department_id),
constraint type_total_fk foreign key (type_id) references type_total_table(type_id)
);
create index t_indx_type_fk on total_table(type_id); -- всегда делайте индекс на внешний ключ
```

на будущее при проектировании структуры придерживайтесь 3х нормальных форм- зачастую их достаточно.